# C++ packing a typedef enum

Tags: c++, c, enums, compilation, packing

```
typedef enum BeNeLux
{
   BELGIUM,
   NETHERLANDS,
   LUXEMBURG
} _ASSOCIATIONS_ BeNeLux;
```

When I try to compile this with C++ Compiler, I am getting errors, but it seems to work fine with a C compiler. So here's the question. Is it possible to pack an enum in C++, or can someone see why I would get the error?

The error is:

> "semicolon missing after declaration of BeNeLux".

I know, after checking and rechecking, that there definitely is a semicolon there, and in any places required in the rest of the code.

Addendum:

`_PACKAGE_` was just an example. I am renaming it.

`_ASSOCIATIONS_` is not a type of BeNeLux:

`#define _ASSOCIATIONS_ __attribute__((packed))`

The code is iffed, but only to make sure it is GNU C/C++.

```
#if defined (__GNUC__) 
#define _ASSOCIATIONS_ __attribute__((packed))
#else
#define _ASSOCIATIONS_
```

Would this cause problems? I thought (**GNUC**) worked for both C and C++

Addendum 2:

I even tried

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef enum BeNeLux
    {
       BELGIUM,
       NETHERLANDS,
       LUXEMBURG
    } _ASSOCIATIONS_ BeNeLux;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

No joy. Anyone?

Note: -fshort-enums is not a possibility; looking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: This is a nonstandard feature. What C compiler are you using?

Comment: Using gcc 3.3.5 or lower (have to use this older version)

Comment: What do you mean by packing an enum?  Making the underlying type as small as possible?

Comment: Both `_PACK_` and `_PACKAGE_` are illegal as user-defined macro names. Names beginning with underscore(s) are basically reserved for compiler's internal identifiers and standard library implementations. (The rules are more complicated, but just don't use leading underscores.)

Comment: @UncleBens: Leading underscores is not a problem here, since I can compile fine with a C compiler. 
@David: Yes. This is for embedded programming

Comment: @Sagar: "can compile" does not mean legal. What UncleBens said is correct. But that's besides the point.

Comment: @Evan: I realise that, but like I said...that is not the issue.

Comment: While it would be good to have the answer here on SO too, doesn't it make sense to ask this on a GCC mailing list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

For C++11 and later, you can specify the underlying type of `enum`s. For example:

```
enum BeNeLux : uint8_t {
   BELGIUM,
   NETHERLANDS,
   LUXEMBURG
};
```

But this only applies if the code will be C++ only. If the code needs to be compatible with both C and C++, I believe my original answer still applies.

---

I don't think that there is something that does **exactly** what you want here. I assume you are trying to create a type that is the smallest type for the enum's range.

If you need this type of control, I would recommend something like this:

```
typedef unsigned char BeNeLux;
static const BeNeLux BELGIUM = 0;
static const BeNeLux NETHERLANDS = 1;
static const BeNeLux LUXEMBURG = 2;
```

not quite as pretty and possibly a little less type safe. But has the effect that you want. `sizeof(BeNeLux) == 1` and you have a named constant for all values in the range. A good compiler won't even allocate a variable for `static const` integer values so long as you never attempt to use the address of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined (__GNUC__)
#  if defined (__cplusplus)
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X) __attribute__((packed))
#  else
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X) __attribute__((packed)) X
#  endif
#else
#  if defined (__cplusplus)
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X)
#  else
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X) X
#  endif
#endif

typdef enum BeNeLux {
  BELGIUM,
  NETHERLANDS,
  LUXEMBURG
} _ASSOCIATIONS_ (BeNeLux);
```

This seems to compile in my `g++ (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)`

Comment: Hi Meera, it works for us with g++ versions above 4 too. The problem is we have to use version 3.3.5 or lower (above comments).

Comment: I made another try... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791739/c-packing-a-typedef-enum/2916024#2916024

Answer (score 1):

There are no real breakthroughs here.  I just reordered things in the hopes that your
compiler would like it better.  I did not have your version of gcc or g++ so I could not test with those.  I did run it through version 3.4.5 gcc and g++ (mingw special) which both warned `'packed' attribute ignored` when ordered like your code, but did not complain about mine.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define attribute(x) __attribute__((x));
#else
#define attribute(x)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

enum BeNeLux
{
    BELGIUM,
    NETHERLANDS,
    LUXEMBURG
} attribute(packed);
// I declared attribute to look like a f() so that it would not look like I was
// declaring a variable here.

#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef enum BeNeLux BeNeLux; // the typedef is separated into a separate stmt
#else
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using GCC and G++. The code compiles fine with either, for me. It would be rather suprising to see such a feature disappear when enabling C++ on any one particular compiler.

Make sure that your `#define` is not `#if`'ed out for C++ code, e.g. `#ifndef __cplusplus`.

Try `g++ -E` to see the preprocessor output and verify that the `#define` appears.

Also, even for preprocessor macros, names beginning with an underscore and capital letter or two underscores are reserved for the compiler and library. If you must have a macro, `PACKED` might be the best name for it.

Comment: Added that code directly without the #ifs and it still did not work.

Comment: @Sagar: try both `gcc -v` and `g++ -v` to make sure you're getting the same version of both.

Comment: According to the manual http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html#SEC105 this should work even in GCC 2.95.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you don't need the `typedef`.  Just start with `enum BeNeLux`.  It's also possible (I can never remember) that declaring a type and a variable with the same identifier may not be legal in one of the languages.

Comment: the addendum makes clear that's not what he wants. Declaring type and identifier simultaneously is impossible in both languages.

Comment: I mean, declaring `typedef` and identifier simultaneously is impossible in both.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum BeNeLux
{
   BELGIUM,
   NETHERLANDS,
   LUXEMBURG
};
```

This is what is expected of C++ code.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If he just used this, then he would be finished.

Comment: No. The question is for "typedef enum" and attribute packing. I know enum BeNeLux would work, but that is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if defined (__GNUC__)

#  if defined (__cplusplus)
#     define ENUM enum
#  else
#     define ENUM typedef enum
#  endif

#  if defined (__cplusplus)
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X) __attribute__((packed))
#  else
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X) __attribute__((packed)) X
#  endif
#else
#  if defined (__cplusplus)
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X)
#  else
#     define _ASSOCIATIONS_(X) X
#  endif
#endif

ENUM BeNeLux {
  BELGIUM,
  NETHERLANDS,
  LUXEMBURG
} _ASSOCIATIONS_ (BeNeLux);
```

Another snippet. see the new `#define ENUM`